# Customize Google Toolbar to use querystring parameters for search

Tags: internet-explorer-9, google-toolbar

I like using the google toolbar but I would like it to use:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?tbs=qdr:y
```

as the default search when I type in terms.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE9.